# dplyr table reconstructing/data wrangling

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, data-cleaning

I'm trying to create a variable that defines true vs false searches. The original dataset is located here: https://github.com/wikimedia-research/Discovery-Hiring-Analyst-2016/blob/master/events_log.csv.gz

The basic scenario is that there are variables that define how many times a user (defined by ID- either session_id or uuid in the original dataset) performs a true search vs a false search, such that a visit is always preceded by a search, but a search does not have to be followed by a visit. If you check the original dataset there is also a time variable, timestamp,  that I do not know how to replicate but I believe will be useful.

A sketchy version of the original structure:

```
ID  Action   Time
a   search    1
a   visit     2
a   search    3
a   visit     4
b   visit     2
b   visit     3
b   search    1
c   search    5
c   search    6
c   search    7
c   visit     8
d   search    3
d   search    4
```

I'm trying to create a variable that defines true vs false searches. 
The above data is expected to be sorted by Action = search only such as in the following format:

Structure I'm trying to produce:

```
ID  Action ClickThrough
a   search    T
a   search    T
b   search    T
c   search    F
c   search    F
c   search    T
d   search    F
d   search    F
```

Comment: How is the `b` search `TRUE`? If that's a typo, you could do it with `actions %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(ClickThrough = lead(Action, default = 'left') == 'visit') %>% filter(Action == 'search')`

Comment: @alistaire The third b is a search, which could be followed by a visit. Action is not in order.

Comment: Then you need time information in your data.

Comment: @alistaire Do you think this will do? `actions %>% group_by(ID) %>% arrange(ID, time) %>% mutate(ClickThrough = lead(Action, default = 'left') == 'visit') %>% filter(Action == 'search')`

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing what `time` is. You need to edit your question to make your example reproducible.

Comment: @alistaire I edited my post, tried my best to replicate time var from the original dataset. Some events overlaps, thus time will be the same..

Comment: If you can get to that point, yes, adding `arrange` will do the trick. It sounds like there may be some munging to get there, though.

Comment: @alistaire why do you define `default = 'left'` in lead function?

Comment: It can't be `NA` (the default default) or `"visit"`, but anything else is fine. Since it will be for the last value, I assumed they left the site.

Comment: @alistaire what do you mean by "left the site"

Comment: They didn't `"visit"` or `"search"` anymore so...they went somewhere else. I assumed? It's not my data.

Comment: @alistaire I'm unable to use the code on the original dataset.. I'm not familiar with the `lead` function, but I think you cannot set it to a value, you have to define it with a variable? And I should be defining clickthrough as T or F instead of visit.. I tried to revise the code:  `action %>% group_by(session_id) %>% arrange(session_id, timestamp) %>% mutate(clickthrough = lead(action, order_by = timestamp) == 'T') %>% filter(action == 'searchPageResult')`  but it still not working...

Comment: See `?lead`, but it just looks up the value of the specified variable for the next row. (The `default` gets used for the last row.) Thus you don't want to set `== "T"`; you want to use `==` to get `TRUE` or `FALSE` for whether the next row matches `"visit"`.

Comment: @alistaire this is the error I'm getting `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Not compatible with requested type: [type=character; target=integer]`

Comment: What type is `Action`? If it's factor, set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` wherever you read in the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces the expected output using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  arrange(ID,Time) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(ClickThrough = c(as.logical(diff(Action=="visit")),FALSE)) %>%
  filter(Action=="search")

# # A tibble: 8 x 4
# # Groups:   ID [4]
#      ID Action  Time ClickThrough
#   <chr>  <chr> <int>        <lgl>
# 1     a search     1         TRUE
# 2     a search     3         TRUE
# 3     b search     1         TRUE
# 4     c search     5        FALSE
# 5     c search     6        FALSE
# 6     c search     7         TRUE
# 7     d search     3        FALSE
# 8     d search     4        FALSE
```