# R dplyr data wrangling/ reconstructing challenge

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I'm trying to record search sessions that have lasted longer or equal to 30 seconds. After arranging the dataset by time and ID, the dataset looks roughly like the following:

```
 ID  Action   Checkin
 a   search    NA
 a   visit     NA
 a   visit     NA
 a   checkin   10
 a   checkin   20
 a   checkin   30
 a   checkin   40
 a   checkin   50
 b   search    NA
 b   search    NA
 b   search    NA
 c   search    NA
 c   search    NA
 d   search    NA
 d   search    NA
 d   visit     NA
 d   checkin   10
 d   checkin   20
 e   search    NA
 e   visit     NA
 e   checkin   10
 e   checkin   20
 e   checkin   30
```

From the above structure, I hope to generate a table that records number of searches by ID, and for each search that does not follow by visit(s) or with checkin time less than 30 seconds, Check30 will be F. For those searches that are followed by visit(s) and with checkin time lasts over 30 seconds, check30 will be T. I tried to filter by `max(Checkin)` and `group_by(ID)` , but I cannot get `Check30` to report by action `search`...

You can refer to this post: 
[dplyr table reconstructing/data wrangling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48800381/dplyr-table-reconstructing-data-wrangling) 
which shows my first attempt to recognize true vs false searches, but now I'm interested in reflecting checkin duration >= 30.

Help is greatly appreciated!

Aiming for a table looks such as the follow:

```
ID  Action   Check30
 a   search    T
 b   search    F
 b   search    F
 b   search    F
 c   search    F
 c   search    F
 d   search    F
 d   search    F
 e   search    T
```

To kgolyaev:

I revised your code to fit in with the original dataset (https://github.com/wikimedia-research/Discovery-Hiring-Analyst-2016/blob/master/events_log.csv.gz)
After left join by session_id I ended up with 237953 obs, but I believe obs should match up with the `seaches`, which is 136234 obs.

```
# pick all searches
searches <-  eventLog %>% 
filter(action == 'searchResultPage') %>% 
dplyr :: select(-checkin)

# pick all visits

visits <- eventLog %>% 
filter(action == 'visitPage') %>% 
dplyr :: select(-action)

# do a left join and create variable of interest

searchesAndVisits <- searches %>% 
left_join(visits, by = 'session_id', suffix = c("_search", "_visit")) %>% 
mutate( check30 = "FALSE", condition = ((checkin >= 30) & timestamp_search < 
timestamp_visit), check30=ifelse(condition, "TRUE", check30))
```

Comment: Please show a desired output. Right now you reference counting the number of searches per ID, but none of the tables above show a count at all.

Comment: To do this correctly, there has to be another column that 'orders' actions within ID. You mention time, but it is not shown in the example data. Without time, it's not clear whether search was followed by a visit, or a visit was followed by search.

Comment: @leeum if you do filter by action == "search" you will get to the structure of the second table.

Comment: Yea I get how you made the second table. I don't get what your desired output looks like. Create an example table that highlights the desired output.

Comment: @kgolyaev I arranged the data by time already, the events are in ascending order of time? Do you still wish for to produce a column for time? It may just  be an ordered numbers..

Comment: @leeum my desired output is to create a variable, Check30, that defines search to be T if the search lasts or equal to 30 seconds, the search duration is defined by `checkin` . Check30 will the F if the search is not followed with a visit or checkin duration is less than 30. Check30 will be reflecting ID action search, and that is the part I'm struggling with.. I hope that clarifies..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a much smaller example with an additional column for time. Hope this helps. This uses package `dplyr`. I added an ID where visit happens prior to search to illustrate that this code handles this case as well.

```
library('dplyr')
df <- readr::read_csv("ID,Action,Checkin,time
a,search,NA,1
a,visit,NA,2
b,search,NA,1
c,search,NA,1
c,visit,30,2
c,checkin,40,3
d,visit,30,1
d,search,NA,2")
df
# A tibble: 8 x 4
ID  Action Checkin  time
<chr>   <chr>   <int> <int>
1     a  search      NA     1
2     a   visit      NA     2
3     b  search      NA     1
4     c  search      NA     1
5     c   visit      30     2
6     c checkin      40     3
7     d   visit      30     1
8     d  search      NA     2
```

Split into searches and visits:

```
# pick all searches
searches <- df %>% 
  filter(Action == 'search') %>% 
  select(-Checkin)
# pick all visits
visits <- df %>% 
  filter(Action == 'visit') %>% 
  select(-Action)
```

Now join the data and massage them into needed shape.

```
# do a left join and create variable of interest
searchesAndVisits <- searches %>% 
  left_join(visits, by = 'ID', suffix = c("_search", "_visit")) %>% 
mutate(
    Check30 = "F"
    , condition = ( (Checkin >= 30) & !is.na(Checkin) # checkin at least 30 sec
                    & time_search < time_visit) # checkin after search 
    , Check30 = ifelse(condition,  "T", Check30)
  ) %>% 
  select(ID, Action, Check30)
searchesAndVisits
# A tibble: 4 x 3
ID Action Check30
<chr>  <chr>   <chr>
1     a search       F
2     b search       F
3     c search       T
4     d search       F
```

**UPDATE**

This strategy will create one row in the final data for each pair of 'search' and 'visit' per id. Consider the following example.

```
df2 <- readr::read_csv("ID,Action,Checkin,time
a,search,NA,1
a,visit,30,2
a,search,NA,3
a,visit,40,4")
df2
# A tibble: 4 × 4
     ID Action Checkin  time
  <chr>  <chr>   <int> <int>
1     a search      NA     1
2     a  visit      30     2
3     a search      NA     3
4     a  visit      40     4
```

Here I created two searches and two visits for the same ID. If you run the same code I wrote previously and make it return two more variables, `time_search` and `time_visit`, you will get this output:

```
searchesAndVisits
# A tibble: 4 × 5
     ID Action Check30 time_search time_visit
  <chr>  <chr>   <chr>       <int>      <int>
1     a search       T           1          2
2     a search       T           1          4
3     a search       F           3          2
4     a search       T           3          4
```

You now have four rows. Each of the two searches is paired with each of the two visits. First row is search at time 1 paired with visit at time 2. Second row is search at time 1 paired with visit at time 4. Third row is search at time 3 paired with visit at time 2. And last row is search at time 3 paired with visit at time 4.

You can most likely delete the third row, saying that it is not reasonable to pair visits with searches if visit happened prior to search. But what do you want to do about row 2? It formally satisfies your requirement: "search after visit, checkin time at least 30 seconds". This is where extra rows will come from, and you need to decide how to handle them.

Comment: Hi I applied your code to the original dataset and have  updated the original addressing to your code, but I think the result is over counting because of the left join.  Thank you for help me..

Comment: I suspect that you have multiple searches and visits per id. Then the join on id only will indeed increase the number of records. You can drop records where search_time < visit_time, but ultimately that is not a perfect fix. What if you have one search followed by 2 visits? Then my code creates 2 records, one per each search-visit pair. How do you propose to disambiguate this case?

Comment: Yes, there will be multiple visits after a search for the same ID, and in the original dataset there is another variable `uuid` which is unique for every obs. I suppose I can use that? However, I tried to left join with that variable before the dataset created was empty for check30.

Comment: uuid won't help - this is like a page-hit id, which will be different every time user visits a page, even if it is the same page. Please see my update and let me know if it helps.

Comment: when you created "searches" and "visits" datasets, element "checkin" was neglected. When the merge was performed no checkin was selected and all results were False..."search" and "visit" always pair with NA "checkin"

Comment: I think I figured out a way that uses mainly dplyr without joining for the wrangling. Thank you for the help!